# Split comma delimited cell into multiple rows, keeping row details

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for a piece of app script or formulas which would transform something like the first example below into something like the second, Where the cell of multiple locations is split into new rows and retains the original row values. Does anyone please have any suggestions?

Kind regards

[image]
[image]

Comment: would it be possible to share a copy of your spreadsheet? I think I may be able to help you.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xLFMpStvXvBse5WeIEKC-8zoOMCgG_RraWOaoVfxAT8/edit?usp=drivesdk&urp=gmail_link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save this script in the script editor

```js
/** 
 * Splits the array by commas in the column with given index, by given delimiter
 * @param {A2:B20}  range Range reference
 * @param {2}  colToSplit Column index
 * @param {","}  delimiter Character by which to split
 * @customfunction
 */


function advancedSplit(range, colToSplit, delimiter) {
    var resArr = [], row;
    range.forEach(function (r) {
        r[colToSplit-1].toString().split(delimiter)
            .forEach(function (s) {
                row = [];
                r.forEach(function (c, k) {               
                    row.push( (k === colToSplit-1) ? s.trim() : c);
                })
                resArr.push(row);
            })
    })
    return resArr;
}
```

Then in a second tab enter this formula

```
=advancedSplit(Sheet1!A:F, 6, ", ")
```

and see if that works?

**Source data:**

[image: Source data]

**Output:**

[image: Output]