# Divide cell by the number of people

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Guys I have little problem. I have output from other system to google spreadsheet.

I need to make a worksheet so that all data from this cell is divided into separate rows and the number next to it (D4) divided by the number of separate persons (a = first person, b=2nd person etc) (C4).

So far I have this script (other topic from stack ) -> [Split comma delimited cell into multiple rows, keeping row details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60547680/split-comma-delimited-cell-into-multiple-rows-keeping-row-details/60549735#60549735)

```
/** 
 * Splits the array by commas in the column with given index, by given delimiter
 * @param {A2:B20}  range Range reference
 * @param {2}  colToSplit Column index
 * @param {","}  delimiter Character by which to split
 * @customfunction
 */


function advancedSplit(range, colToSplit, delimiter) {
    var resArr = [], row;
    range.forEach(function (r) {
        r[colToSplit-1].toString().split(delimiter)
            .forEach(function (s) {
                
                row = [];
                r.forEach(function (c, k) {               
                    row.push( (k === colToSplit-1) ? s.trim() : c);
                })
                resArr.push(row);
                
            })
     
    })
    
    return resArr.filter(function (r) {
        return r.toString()
        
            
    })

    
}
```

The problem with dividing a cell by ";" is solved, but not with dividing a cell with a number of persons (phrases)

Sample:

cell A1 contains {a,b,c,d,e,f} and B2 1000

output:
a 200
b 200
c 200
d 200
e 200
f 200

This is dynamic data with 1000+ rows. An appscript should be used in this case

[image: Input and output]

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what is the expect "dividing a cell with a number" result and add the sample data as text rather than as image.

Comment: I added an example

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/).  Use [code fences](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to format your code. [Test formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) before posting questions.

Comment: It looks like you copied this from somewhere else. If you're using someone else's work without giving them credit, that constitutes plagiarism, which is not welcome on Stack Exchange. To fix it, you can [edit], include a [link](/editing-help#links) to the source, mention the author's name, and [quote](/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) the copied content. For more details, see [referencing help](/help/referencing) and [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160077/343832).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not intended to be a cell function but as a standard function it provides the desired output.

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,2,4).getValues();
  let a = [];
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    let c2 = r[2].toString().split(",");
    c2.forEach(e => {
      a.push([r[0],r[1],e,r[3]/c2.length]);
    });
  });
  osh.clearContents();
  osh.getRange(2,1,a.length,a[0].length).setValues(a);
}
```

input:

| data1 | data2 | a,b,c,d,e | 1000 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| data3 | data4 | f,g,h,i | 2000 |

output:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| data1 | data2 | a | 200 |
| data1 | data2 | b | 200 |
| data1 | data2 | c | 200 |
| data1 | data2 | d | 200 |
| data1 | data2 | e | 200 |
| data3 | data4 | f | 500 |
| data3 | data4 | g | 500 |
| data3 | data4 | h | 500 |
| data3 | data4 | i | 500 |

Try it this way for more rows and columns

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();//gets the entire column
  let a = [];
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    let c2 = r[2].toString().split(",");
    c2.forEach(e => {
      let row = r.slice();//keeps each element of the output array independent
      row.splice(2,2,e,row[3]/c2.length);//replace elements 2 and 3
      a.push(row);
    });
  });
  osh.clearContents();
  osh.getRange(2,1,a.length,a[0].length).setValues(a);
}
```

Comment: Do you know how I can merge this with my function? There is more collumns and rows... rows about 1k and collumns to T+

Comment: There is a lot of important data for future reports :)

Comment: Okay that should handle more rows and columns

Comment: Nice idea:P But I'm still stupid:P

Comment: I imagine that there is a message in your last comment but it's not clear to me what it is.

Comment: :P That I'm still stupid and don't understand AppScript:P I'm trying to understand how the script works

Comment: What is the reason for your use of `:P`

Comment: I got It:) Thank You very much:)

@Cooper reason?:) This is output from JIRA (the number of columns is the same, but the number of rows keeps growing) . I need it to create reports, dashboards etc:) I'm not developer:(  Unfortunately I only know the basics of JavaScript:)