# Look up Values from different Tabs and sumup the score and print

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Facing difficulties in solving this problem.

I am writing a script with the below conditions for my calculations based on my Google Sheets.

`Tab 1` has comma-separated text, which I want to split and then look up each spitted text  with `Tab2` where I have data range from `A2:C` where If A column text matches then it should check the values from column C and sumup and then print.

This is what a wrote..

```
function score(cell) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("AQ2:AQ");
  var values = range.getValues();
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var valuesInCommaSeparatedString = values[i][0].split(",");
    for (var j = 0; j < valuesInCommaSeparatedString.length; j++) {
      var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Error Categories");
      var range2 = sheet2.getRange("B2:D");
      var values2 = range2.getValues();
      for (var k = 0; k < values2.length; k++) {
        if (valuesInCommaSeparatedString[j] == values2[k][0]) {
          sum += values2[k][2];
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Also, I tried this, but no luck ...

```
function searchCommaSeparatedText() {
  // Get the text to search from cell B2 in sheet 1.
  var text = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Precheck").getRange("AQ2:AQ").getValue();

  // Split the text into an array of strings.
  var words = text.split(",");

  // Get the data range in sheet 2.
  var dataRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Error Categories").getRange("B2:D");

  // Initialize the sum of the matched values.
  var sum = 0;

  // Iterate over the words.
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    // Search for the word in column B of the data range.
    var match = dataRange.findText(words[i], SpreadsheetApp.FindOption.MATCH_CASE_SENSITIVE);

    // If the word is found, then add the corresponding value in column D to the sum.
    if (match != null) {
      sum += dataRange.getValue(match.row, 3);
    }
  }

  // Print the sum in cell B2 of sheet 1.
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Precheck").getRange("CB2:CB").setValue(sum);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow! Please take this opportunity to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn how to [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [format the code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [etc](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).

Comment: Would you be able to provide your sample sheet, with your initial output, and also your expected output so that we can further help you with this?

Comment: Providing an initial output with your expected output should help in this context. It can be a tabular form in Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You have a single spreadsheet that contains two sheets:

- **Tab1**

  - cells in Column A contain comma separated strings. ALL of the separated words are listed in Column A of sheet "Tab2"
- **Tab2**

  - cells in Column A contain words
  - cells in Column C contains values

You want to:

- calculate the total value of the separated words from Sheet "Tab1" by referencing the corresponding values on sheet "Tab2"
- inserting the total value in cell B1 of "Tab1"

---

```
function printTotal() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var tab1 = ss.getSheetByName("Tab1")
  var tab2 = ss.getSheetByName("Tab2")

  // get Tab1 data
  var tab1LR = tab1.getLastRow()
  var tab1Range = tab1.getRange(1,1,tab1LR,1)
  var tab1Data = tab1Range.getValues()
 
  // split cells in the range and create an array
  var delimiter = ","
  var colToSplit = 1
  var tab1Names = [], row;
  tab1Data.forEach(function (r) {
    r[colToSplit-1].toString().split(delimiter)
      .forEach(function (s) {
        row = [];
        r.forEach(function (c, k) {               
          row.push( (k === colToSplit-1) ? s.trim() : c);
        })
      tab1Names.push(row);
      })
  })
  // Logger.log(tab1Names) // DEBUG
  // Logger.log(tab1Names.length) // DEBUG

  // get tab2 data
  var tab2Data = tab2.getDataRange().getValues()
  // Logger.log(tab2Data) // DEBUG
  // convert to a 1D array
  var tab2Names = tab2Data.map(function(e){return e[0]})
  // Logger.log(tab2Names)
  
  var nameValues = []
  for (var i=0;i<tab1Names.length;i++){
    var result = tab2Names.indexOf(tab1Names[i][0]);
    var nameValue = tab2Data[result][2]
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: i:"+i+", name = "+tab1Names[i][0]+", result = "+result+", value = "+nameValue)
    nameValues.push(nameValue)
  }
  // Logger.log(nameValues) // DEBUG
  var total =  nameValues.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: total = "+total)
  tab1.getRange("B1").setValue(total)
  
}
```

---

**Sample - Tab1**

[image: tab1]

**Sample - Tab2**

[image: tab2]

---

h/t @JPV for [Split comma delimited cell into multiple rows, keeping row details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60549735/1330560)